Find X Atom of given Window?
Using DWM as my Window-Manager under Archlinux I don't have any patches to handle context menus or "right-click" functionalities.
This being the case I decided to write a concise Bash alias that runs xclip (which I can later re-map to mouse buttons using libinput and such).
My issue now though is that I am trying to re-direct my xclip selections to a specific window but I'm not finding how I can grab the X Atom with any commands so far.
I've tried xprop and xwininfo but none of the data returned matches the Atom.
Any help or insight is appreciated.

I don't understand what you want to do, but for low-level X11 coding you might be interested by the version of xlib written entirely in Python. It has a demo xlsatoms.py.

@meuh I've been thinking about how I phrased the question because it might be a case of X-Y as it is.

xprop (1) returns the atom when given its name as an argument. For example, executing xprop WM_PROTOCOLS, and clicking on an st window returns: WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, To return an atom programmatically given its name, there is, for example, Xlib function XInternAtom (3).

xprop(1) returns the atom when given its name as an argument. For example, executing
xprop WM_PROTOCOLS

and clicking on an st window returns:
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW

while doing the same and instead clicking on the Ungoogled Chromium window gives
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST

To return an atom programmatically given its name, there is, for example, Xlib function XInternAtom(3).
One of the X.Org apps is xlsatoms, which lists all atoms defined on the X server. As @meuh mentioned, there is a version of it written in Python, contained in the package python-xlib in the directory examples.
